# How to layout images in knockouts

Tags: html, knockout.js

I wish to layout images (three horizontally across the page) and then down.
At the moment I have the html below and I get single image on each line...  (like records listed on a page).

```
<!-- Security Layout -->

<div data-bind="visible: securityLayoutVisible">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Security View</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="foreach: securityViewCameraArray">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.overlayImageOpen">
                        <img class="cameraSecurity" data-bind="attr : {src: fields.url.value}, {alt: fields.title.value}"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this style:

```
img.cameraSecurity {
    width: 340px;
    height: 260px;
    display: inline-box;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

What do I need to change to get the images displaying...

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

or

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

instead of

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

- David

Comment: output is inside of every div right? you can create a fiddle

Comment: That is wonderful. I've removed the two <div>'s and now have the result I want. Thank you.